# Delegate Loop not changing behavior between C# 5 and C# 4 Version as per text book

Tags: c#

I have another fairly unimportant theory question but I was hoping to find clarity on this anyhow. As per a text book I have, it states the the following code should have different results from C# version 4 to C# version 5:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var values = new List<int> { 10, 20, 30 };
        var funcs = new List<Func<int>>();
        foreach (var value in values)
        {
            funcs.Add(() => value);
        }
        foreach(var f in funcs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine((f()));
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

According to the material I have, in C# version 4, 30 should be written to the console 3 times due to the following:

> With C# 4 the compiler defines the loop variable outside of the while
>   loop and reuses it with every iteration. Thus, at the end of the loop
>   the variable has the value from the last iteration.

And in C# 5, the values 10, 20, 30 should be written to the console however, despite changing the C# version (I'm definitely changing the language version and not the .NET framework (although I've tried that as well)) both version write 10, 20, 30 to the console.

I realize this isn't very important but I'm just wondering why this is as it might be something I'm doing wrong and could influence other tests that I try between language versions of C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The devil is in the details - as you correctly quoted, the old behavior only occurs in the C# 4 **compiler**, not the language or framework itself.

As such, all depends on what *environment* (i.e. Visual Studio) you use to compile the code, regardless of language compatibility level or target framework version chosen.

Comment: Ah man, I didn't think of that. Thanks very much. I'll try setup something on a VM I have to try it out properly there. Thanks so much for spotting that! Much appreciated @Viktor Svub